# Can't upload in subdirectories of a custom home directory

Tags: 16.04, apache2, home-directory, ftp, vsftpd

I have an user called `yazrihm` and i changed his home directory to /var/www with the followings commands:

```
1. chown yazrihm:yazrihm
2. usermod -d /var/www/ yazrihm
```

And i can upload in `/var/www` but not in `/var/www/html`
Log from the FTP Client:

```
Command :   CWD /var/www/html
Answer :    250 Directory successfully changed.
Command :   TYPE A
Answer :    200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command :   PASV
Answer :    227 Entering Passive Mode (149,202,41,67,40,51).
Command :   STOR sprites.lib.php
Answer :    553 Could not create file.
```

Sorry for grammar and thanks for helping.

Comment: please run `ls -l /var/www` and `ls -l /var/www/html` and post the results...

Comment: " i changed his home directory to /var/www " Why????????????  Sorry but... you do realize ---any--- exploit in apache, or the scripting language you use will allow someone to kill your user's home? Security wise you should create a /var/www/{.../}upload/, store the download there, move it to another place outside of your webserver renaming it with a random filename and then pick it up with software you want to do something with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to:

```
chown -R yazrihm:yazrihm /var/www
```

This is needed to be changed the owner of contained (in the target directory) files and sub-directories. From `man chown`:

```
 -R, --recursive
              operate on files and directories recursively
```

This is an answer for the probable solution of the problem, but in your case **keep in mind the [advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884060/cant-upload-in-subdirectories-of-a-custom-home-directory#comment1379576_884060) given to you from Rinzwind**!